# Count down to a time on the serverside Node.JS and send response of a page

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, countdown

I have a question that I just cant seem to find out how to do -

I've seen many clientside countdown plugins and I have one on my app - however I'm interested in counting to a certain date on my server, and once that date and time has arrived, I want to trigger a response to the client with a popup page.

Now - I have tried doing that on the clientside with a countdown.onFinish function. But from how I understand this, it will not work unless the client is in the app ON the time of the countdown finish. Am I correct in assuming that the client script is only generated when a client enters the app? Therefor when the user comes in, the timer would have restarted already (On Login I update the timer to countdown to the nearest monday at 21:00). 
On the Server - I can check if the date has arrived, outside a function, but this would only happen once on deploy, correct?  and if I check it on some kind of intervals, every time I update the app these intervals would get messed up and I might miss the 00:00 hour.

This is the idea of what I have on my serveside (Using expressJS, nodeJS)

```
var today = new Date();
var currentDay = today.getDay() + 1;
var currentMonth = today.getMonth() + 1;
var currentDate = today.getDate();
var currentYear = today.getFullYear();
//var date = [02, 22, 2014];
var dateTillMatch = findNearestMonday(currentDay, currentDate, currentMonth, currentYear);
if (dateTillMatch[0] == currentDay && dateTillMatch[1] == currentDate && dateTillMatch[2] == currentMonth && dateTillMatch[3] == currentYear) {
    updateAllStats();
}
```

and this is what I had on my clientside - which did not work - because at the time of 00:00 none of my users were inside the app! (genius I know..)

```
function timer(date) {
    $('#clock').countdown(date[2] + '/' + date[0] + '/' + date[1] + ' 21:30:00', function(event) {
        $(this).html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
    }).on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
        var played = localStorage.getItem('attending');
        //If the player was attending/not attending at end of countdown, send to DB that GamesPlayed ++ or gamesNotPlayed ++
        if (played == 1 || played == -1) {

            var request = false;
            var result = null;
            var name = localStorage.getItem('first') + " " + localStorage.getItem('last');
            request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            if (request) {
                request.open("GET", "usersGamesPlayed/" + name + "_" + played);
                request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                        result = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

                        if (result == null) {
                            alert('PROBLEMO');
                        } else {
                            if (played == 1) {
                                localStorage.setItem('gamesPlayed', parseInt(result.gamesPlayed));
                            } else {
                                localStorage.setItem('gamesNotPlayed', parseInt(result.gamesNotPlayed));
                            }

                            //Set back to 0
                            localStorage.setItem('attending', 0);
                            //Popup to find Best Player
                            console.log("Choose MVP");
                            $('#bestPlayerPopup').popup();
                            $("#bestPlayerPopup").popup("open");

                        }
                    }
                };
                request.send(null);
            }
        }

    });

}
```

So to conclude - I understand that its pointless to wait for the clientside counter to hit 00:00 because "If a tree falls and no one is there to hear it, does it make a sound?" - or something :)
So how do I do the same on the server? AND - on the end of time, how do I send the user a popup - or atleast redirect him to a page. Will I need to bind it to some request from the client? because than it defeats the purpose of doing it on 00:00. 
My DB is MongoDB so I can use that if necessary.

I hope the question isn't too long!
Thank you

Comment: Google maybe?: http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use websockets (http://socket.io). Use the node.js timer-api on the server to generate the event, which sends the necessary data to all clients that are listening (viewing your countdown-page).

On the client side you catch the event, and then either update your current page with the recieved data, or make a new get-request to your "countdown finished"-page.

Comment: Hi - Thanks! - question: If the timer-api will generate the event and send the data to clients listening, what happens to clients who aren't listening at the time? doesn't it put me in the same problem? Will the user catch the response when he enters the app? Also - how do I catch the event on the client? If I didn't make a request to the server, how do I know to listen to a response?
Hope my question makes sense...t

Comment: Update - I have found a CronJobs plug in for NodeJS that can let me generate events based on a date. BUT - Still my question remains - Once the date has arrived, I want to send something to the user. But if there is no client available, will he receieve this when he logs in? do I need to tell the client to ALWAYS listen for this event? I am lacking some understanding on this subject...

Comment: socket.io has a fairly easy to follow guide regarding how to send/receive events both server- and client-side. I would suggest you start there. Have your clients always request the status of the countdown upon login, that will take care of users entering the page after the event has fired.

Comment: Yes, this is what I assumed. But say this - 
My counter on the server has ended (meaning the date has arrived). The client always requests the status of the countdown (with socket.io). By the time the user logged in, the counter on the server has already re-set. I feel like even with this solution I need the client to be online when the timer hits 00:00

Comment: Then give each countdown an ID. Then have the user request the status of that countdown when he/she logs in.

Comment: Thank you ! this should solve it...
What do you think of this solution - Once the event is triggered on server, I update a field in the user collection DB of something like gameEnded:true. when He logs, I check on the client if its true etc...